Infinite intersections of sets of the form $ \mathbb{R} \setminus \{ i \} $
This morning in a lecture, our professor stated that the intersection of $\mathbb{R}$ with an infinite amount of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, where each omit a single (unique) value from it is equal to the null set. I interpret that as follows:
$$ {\bigcap}_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb{R} \setminus \{a_i\} = \varnothing ,$$
where $\forall i \in \mathbb{N},\; a_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and if $ a_b = a_c \implies b=c $.
This does not sit right with me.
My reasoning is that since we are removing a single value per intersection, we should be able to remove countably infinite elements from $\mathbb{R}$. But since $\mathbb{R}$ contains uncountably many values, we should not be able to remove all of them, however many times we repeat the above process.
An explanation of how the above is possible (and where my reasoning breaks apart) would be greatly appreciated.

Your reasoning is correct.  You could do an uncountable intersection, but I don't believe you're guaranteed to cover all of $\mathbb{R}$ there either.

Letting the sequence be the natural numbers is a counterexample, you're correct.

Seems likely you misunderstood what the lecturer was saying. What you have written certainly isn't true.

In particular, it is not true for all sets of subsets of this form. Indeed, if $S\subseteq \mathbb R,$ you get: $$\bigcap_{x\in S} \left(\mathbb R\setminus{x} \right)\iff S=\mathbb R.$$

Your interpretation is incorrect. The intersection of all sets $\mathbb R\setminus{x}$ is empty where $x$ ranges over all real numbers. I doubt he wrote a countable intersection.

I suppose it depends on the "infinity" being referenced. You could certainly take an uncountable intersection:
$$
\bigcap_{r \in \mathbb{R}} \mathbb{R} \setminus \{r\} = \emptyset
$$
If your professor explicitly meant what was written in your post, however, then that is incorrect of them since that would be a countable intersection. Taking $a_n = n$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, for instance, we would see that $-1$ lies in the intersection quite obviously, among many others.

If this is really what Prof said, then Prof is wrong.
A straightforward application of De Morgan shows that this set
$$\bigcap_{i=0}^{\infty} (\mathbb{R}\setminus\{a_i\}) = \mathbb{R}\setminus\bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty}\{a_i\}$$
is the complement of a countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Not only isn't it empty but in fact it is uncountable and dense in $\mathbb{R}$.
